# Inequality $\frac{x_1}{x_k+x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_1+x_3}+\dots+\frac{x_k}{x_{k-1}+x_1}\geq 2.$

Tags: inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that for any positive numbers $x_1, x_2,\dots, x_k$ $(k>3)$ the following inequality is true: $$\frac{x_1}{x_k+x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_1+x_3}+\dots+\frac{x_k}{x_{k-1}+x_1}\geq 2.$$

The case when $k=4$ can be reduced to the inequality $a+\frac{1}{a}\geq 2$ so in this case everything is fine.

But for $k>4$ I do not see the way how to prove that inequality.

Can you show the solution please?

**P.S.** It seems like a Nesbitt inequality which states that if $a,b,c>0$ then $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq \frac{3}{2}$. I do know how to prove that one. We can make substitution $b+c=x, a+c=y, a+b=z$ and the rest is quite obvious.

Comment: There seem to be various solutions on AoPS: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bx_1%7D%7Bx_k%2Bx_2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx_2%7D%7Bx_1%2Bx_3%7D%2B%5Cdots%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx_k%7D%7Bx_%7Bk-1%7D%2Bx_1%7D%5Cgeq%202.%24

Comment: [This could be useful.](http://olympiads.mccme.ru/lktg/2010/5/5-1en.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @MartinR!

Comment: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Shapiro_inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_{k+1}=x_1$ and $x_0=x_k.$

Thus, by C-S $$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{x_i}{x_{i-1}+x_{i+1}}=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{x_i^2}{x_{i-1}x_i+x_{i+1}x_i}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{l=1}^kx_i\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^k(x_{i-1}x_i+x_ix_{i+1})}=\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{l=1}^kx_i\right)^2}{2\sum\limits_{i=1}^kx_ix_{i+1}}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\left(\sum\limits_{l=1}^kx_i\right)^2\geq4\sum\limits_{i=1}^kx_ix_{i+1}.$$

Now, for any even $k$ by AM-GM
$$4\sum_{i=1}^kx_ix_{i+1}\leq4(x_1+x_3+...+x_{k-1})(x_2+x_4+...+x_k)\leq$$
$$\leq(x_1+x_3+...+x_{k-1}+x_2+x_4+...+x_k)^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^kx_i\right)^2.$$
For odd $k$ since our inequality is cyclic, we can assume that $x_1=\min\{x_i\}$ and by AM-GM again:
$$4\sum_{i=1}^kx_ix_{i+1}\leq4(x_1+x_3+...+x_{k})(x_2+x_4+...+x_{k-1})\leq$$
$$\leq(x_1+x_3+...+x_{k}+x_2+x_4+...+x_{k-1})^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^kx_i\right)^2.$$

Comment: This inequality looks correct to me intuitively $\left(\sum\limits_{l=1}^kx_i\right)^2-4\sum\limits_{i=1}^kx_ix_{i+1}\geq(x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4+...)^2$. But could you show the rigorous proof of this please?

Comment: @ZFR  In the left and in the right sides we have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k(x_i^2-2x_ix_{i+1})$. The rest adds they are like $a\geq-a$ or $a\geq a$ for positive $a$.

Comment: Sorry but to be honest I did not get your last comment. Could you clarify more please? What do you mean by "in the left and in the right sides we have ..."?

Comment: @ZFR  I added something see now. Also, I added another reasoning by AM-GM.

Comment: Am I right that you claim that $(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_5)^2=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{5}(x_i^2+2x_ix_{i+1})+2\sum \limits_{i=1}^{5}x_ix_{i+2}$?

Comment: You wrote that $(\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k}x_i)^2-4\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k}x_ix_{i+1}\geq (x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4+\dots)^2$ but I don't think that this is true since if I take $k=3$ you will get the reverse inequality.

Comment: Sorry but I think that some parts of your solution needs a clarification. As I pointed above some of them seems wrong to me.

Comment: @ZFR See please better your given. Just k>3. See my second reasoning. I think it's better. I deleted the first reasoning. Ask your questions now.

Comment: When $k$ is odd and our inequality is cyclic and you assumed that $x_1$ is the minimal one. Then how did you obtain an inequality?

Comment: @ZFR For odd $k$,  when you open $(x_1+x_3+...+x_k)(x_2+x_4+...+x_{k-1})$ you obtain any addends from $\sum\limits_{i=1}^kx_ix_{i+1}$ besides $x_1x_k$. Are you agree?

Comment: Probably you meant $x_1x_k$ right? Yes I agree with that. So what is next?

Comment: @ZFR  Now use $x_1x_k\leq x_2x_k$

Comment: I think that I got your point! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing $k$ from $j$ to $j+1$ increases the left-hand side by$$\frac{x_{j+1}}{x_j+x_1}+\color{red}{\frac{x_1}{x_{j+1}+x_2}-\frac{x_1}{x_j+x_2}}+\color{blue}{\frac{x_j}{x_{j-1}+x_{j+1}}-\frac{x_j}{x_{j-1}+x_1}}.$$With the above coloration, each monochromatic part is non-negative if we label the $j+1$ variables so $x_{j+1}$ is minimal. While we can't arbitrarily permute the $x_i$, we can, through rotation of the list of fractions, place the one with least numerator last, so this $x_{j+1}$-is-least convention handles the general case of the inductive step.